# Why am I getting undefine?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I want to make setLoading function from "Screen" to be available in "HomeScreen". So

**context.js**

```
import { createContext } from "react";
export const LoadingContext = createContext();
```

**screen.js**
This is screen component (parent component for HomeScreen). And I want to control the state of Modal in HomeScreen (child component).

```
import { Modal, StyleSheet, View } from "react-native";
import { useMemo, useState } from "react";
import { LoadingContext } from "../../context";

const Screen = ({ children}) => {
   const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

   const loadingContext = useMemo(() => {
      return { setLoading: setLoading };
   }, [loading]);

   return (
      <LoadingContext.Provider value={loadingContext}>
         <View>
            {children}
         </View>
      </LoadingContext.Provider>
   );
};

export default Screen;
```

**HomeScreen.js**

```
import { View, Text } from "react-native";
import { LoadingContext } from "../../context";
import { useContext} from "react";

const HomeScreen = ({ navigation }) => {

   const context = useContext(LoadingContext);

   console.log(context);  // undefined

   return (
      <Screen>
            <Text></Text>
      </Screen>
   );
};


export default HomeScreen;
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is your `useContext` isn't inside your `Screen` component. Read the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext),

> The current context value is determined by the value prop of the nearest <MyContext.Provider> above the calling component in the tree.

Your `useContext` looks up the contexts in parent nodes but fails and hence the undefined value.

Try rapping the `HomeScreen` with `Screen` component when you are using it which I am assuming is your router.

EDIT:
Here's your fix

```
import { View, Text } from "react-native";
import { LoadingContext } from "../../context";
import { useContext} from "react";

const HomeScreen = ({ navigation }) => {

   const context = useContext(LoadingContext);

   console.log(context);  // undefined

   return <Text></Text>;
};

const WrappedHomeScreen = (props) => {
    return <Screen><HomeScreen {...props} /></Screen>;
}

export default WrappedHomeScreen;
```

Comment: Please, can you do it for me? I have tried but still I am not able to do it

Comment: You can try this code. What we are doing here is we are wrapping the `HomeScreen` component and exporting the Wrapped component